# Swift can't segue data from CollectionView to new ViewController

Tags: ios, swift, segue, collectionview

In several places in my app I segue data from a TableView to the following ViewController and it works as simply as this:

```
override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        let indexpath = tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow
        if segue.destination is NewViewController {

                        let name = self.people[indexpath!.row].name
                        let description = self.people[indexpath!.row].desc
                        let vc = segue.destination as? NewViewController
                        vc?.username = name
           
        
        }
```

However this doesn't work at all, for some reason, with a CollectionView (though I feel it absolutely should.)

```
Value of type 'UICollectionView' has no member 'indexPathForSelectedRow'
```

I've also tried most of the suggestions on StackOverflow such as:

```
   let selectedIndexPath = sender as? IndexPath
                let vc = segue.destination as! PlacesViewController
        vc.named = self.places[selectedIndexPath!.row].name as String
```

But all it's gotten me is a nil value.

Why does it not simply work the same way that a tableView would work? (As you'd expect it to in Objective-C... or even as it works with RecyclerView and Gridview in Android...)

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uicollectionview/1618099-indexpathsforselecteditems and get the first one?

Comment: How tableView.indexPathForSelectedRow is giving UICollectionview error? maybe you gave wrong variable?

Comment: It's not. That's an example of what happens when I use the same code (swapping out "tableView with collectionView" of course) on a CollectionView instead of a tableView.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For  collectionView you need to use `indexPathsForSelectedItems`  so try

```
guard let indexpath = collectionView.indexPathsForSelectedItems?.first else { return }
```

> Tip : You better name variables according to their actual type so if it's UITableView to be tableView and if it's UICollectionView  to be collectionView

Comment: So then I should be able to use "let name = self.people[indexpath!].name" to retrieve the individual variable? Or "let name = self.people[indexpath!.row].name"?

Comment: Sure this `let name = self.people[indexpath.row].name`